# R package: how to organize data in subfolders for lazy loading?

Tags: r

I'll like to organize my R package's `data` into `data/models`, `data/samples` etc, and still be able to lazy load the .RData files in these sub folders.
How do you expose the .RData files? Lazy loading so far only works if the .Rdata file is directly in the `data` folder, and not a subfolder.

I've looked at [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages), 
[Creating an R Package](http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/creating-an-r-data-package/) and [Hadley's R Packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html)
but haven't found a way. Is it not possible?

Comment: Excuse me: some things are unclear (to me at least!). Do you want to have more than one .RData right? How do you want to choose the one to lazy load? Thank you ;)

Comment: @Ale yep right now I have a few models, let's say `data/modelA.RData` and `data/modelB.RData`. With `LazyData: true` in my package's `DESCRIPTION`, I can use the models simply by typing `modelA` or `modelB`. I would like the path names to become `data/models/modelA.RData` and `data/models/modelB.RData` though